# phpMyadmin on raspbian with dashboard

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, raspberry-pi, dashboard

Sorry to my english skill but I hope you will understand what I mean.

Firstly, Let me tell you that I use the module to read the energy consumption and send the data (every 3 seconds) into databases which is phpMyadmin.
 
My phpMyadmin was installed on raspberry pi 3 model b (OS: Raspbian) because I want RPi as a server.

So, I want to create a dashboard which it picks the data from phpMyadmin, then show on the dashboard in realtime. The user can connect to this dashboard to see thier energy consumption from inside LOCAL (ex. apartment) and wherever outside the LOCAL.

For exmaple, if the user live in the apartment which is LOCAL, so they just login through the URL :

> 192.168.1.5/energy_dashboard

, some thing like this.
In case the user stay "outside the LOCAL" such as they are abroad. Then they want to see their energy consumption, they just login via URL:

> energydashboard.com/energy_dashboard

I have no idea and experiences about this thing. So, anybody who know what I want to do, PLEASE suggest me how can I beat this challenges.

Thank you very much.

Comment: well this is very broad, and a lot of work, you can start doing it from your own understanding first, and from there you ask questions.

Comment: You need port forwarding set up on your router, if you want them to be able to log into the Pi. You might consider having the Pi send data to a server on the internet so everyone can check their data regardless of which network they're on.